# My first COM import

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have a .h file with the following declarations:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Syntek Plug-In Custom Control GUIDs.                                       //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// {59DF6360-6F14-4472-82B6-6EAB971EEFAD}
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_IStkCustomControl,
            0x59DF6360, 0x6F14, 0x4472, 0x82, 0xB6, 0x6E, 0xAB, 0x97, 0x1E, 0xEF, 0xAD);

// {59DF6361-6F14-4472-82B6-6EAB971EEFAD}
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_IStkCustomControl_PropertyPage,
            0x59DF6361, 0x6F14, 0x4472, 0x82, 0xB6, 0x6E, 0xAB, 0x97, 0x1E, 0xEF, 0xAD);

// Custom Control Interfaces.
MIDL_INTERFACE("59DF6360-6F14-4472-82B6-6EAB971EEFAD")
IStkCustomControl : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Get(PKSPROPERTY_STK_CUSTOM_CONTROL_S pStkCustomControl) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Set(PKSPROPERTY_STK_CUSTOM_CONTROL_S pStkCustomControl) = 0;
};
```

I would like to port the interface `IStkCustomControl` to C#. So far, I have this C# code:

```
Guid guid = new Guid(0x59df6360, 0x6f14, 0x4472, 0x82, 0xb6, 0x6e, 0xab, 0x97, 0x1e, 0xef, 0xad);
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid); // line 2 
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

When executing line 2, I get the exception

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {59DF6360-6F14-4472-82B6-6EAB971EEFAD} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 80040202.

What's going wrong here?

UPDATE: I found out that the `IStkCustomControl` interface is implemented in a file called `StkProp.ax`. I've tried to run `AxImp.exe StkProp.ax`, but that gave me

> AxImp Error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Comment: If you don't have a really good reason to write your own wrapper you should create an automatic wrapper. Either by importing a COM reference in Visual Studio or creating the wrapper by `tlbimp.exe`

Comment: Agreed; it's just that I can't find any .tlb file which contains IStkCustomControl (another mystery).

Comment: That's because it is not an automation compatible interface that derives from IDispatch.  Which makes using it from a managed program perilous.  You'll have to redeclare the COM interfaces in your C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not, the type info is embedded in the DLL that implements the object. Use OLEView to make sure. If so, then set up a COM reference to that DLL and use the auto wrapper.

Having the type info as standalone TLB file is so late nineties.